# When textbox is resized in IE, block position behavior is messed up

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, textarea

i am using the autoresize plugin which increases the height as users type in stuff. It works great on FF/Chrome, but the behavior is messed up on IE (see screenshots below).

Essentially, the textbox, when resized, does not push the rest of the buttons down, which is weird, given that nothing on the page is absolute positioned.

[image: Before textresize]
[image: After textresize]

Comment: A link to an example of the behavior or some actual code would be helpful ... trouble shooting code from a screen shot is ... err ... difficult. Try putting up an example on jsbin.com that replicates the behavior you wish to fix.

Comment: try wrapping the text box in a div to see if that will help push the other controls down.

Comment: @erik hmmm, i was trying not to do so because i was wondering if it was a common IE issue. Can you remove the downvote please? =)

Comment: @mauro already wrapped, cleared, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the button and span on the right are in a relatively positioned container? I've encountered the same problem recently with positioned elements and expanding/collapsing siblings. Still searching for a proper solution, but removing the positioning can be a temp fix.

Comment: thanks a lot! it works! the issue is that I put "position:relative" for all my divs - anyway to "unspecify" this for this particular div?